# How can there be voltage in this electrical configuration. Is there a short?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

I'm having a hard time understanding this electrical setup.  I was wiring a GFCI so I decided to test to see which was the line and load.  I have a switch that seems to control two boxes mounted to my outside soffit.  The switch has two hot leads and I believe there are some neutrals bonded together in the switch box.  These boxes had blanks over them but I decided to wire in an outlet.

I only removed one plate but I *think* that the switch directly feeds hot to the box through the top romex pair.  The box itself then has another romex pair that runs to presumably the other box.  I have no way of confirming this though.  When I removed the blank on the top box I found the neutrals and hots bonded together.  There may be other runs I do not know about but common sense tells me this switch only controls those two boxes.

I decided to separate the wire pairs and noticed the following which does not seem right.  When the switch is on and I tested voltage

- A -> B - 120V
- A -> C - 96V
- A -> D - 96V
- C -> B - 0V
- C -> D - 0V
- When the switch is off everything is at 0V.  The neutrals have 0V.

What I don't get if C\D supposedly dead end to another box how is there voltage against 'D'.  Also how would there be voltage from hot to hot

[image]

Comment: Those cables in the box **are not** Line and Load.  Line are all wires not being protected by this GFCI. Most people expect this GFCI to only protect devices at this outlet. In that case **everything goes on Line**.  If you know what you're doing and want to protect other outlets, yes, you can use Load for that, but you need "GFCI Protected" stickers and you ought to mark where the reset is located too.  If that's not your cuppa, don't use Load terminals.

Answer (score 2):

The A-C and A-D readings are fairly normal for a digital multimeter with a high-impedance input connected between a powered wire and an unconnected wire. If you put an actual load on those connections (like a small incandescent lightbulb) power would not actually flow.

Comment: How would there even be voltage if it's a dead end circuit?  If I connected one end of my DVOM to a hot and the second to a bare wire supposedly going nowhere there wouldn't be around 120V.  Remember I separated all four wires.  I thought you need both ends to have a voltage potential, one end to hot and another end to nowhere is no voltage.

Comment: The wires you are reading voltage on are acting just like a radio antenna. An antenna (especially on a battery-powered portable radio) is basically a piece of wire connected only on one end, and yet it picks up transmitted radio signals. Your wires are picking up 'signals' from other electric and magnetic fields transmitted from other wires and devices in your house. The voltmeter is of a high enough impedance to not swamp out the tiny signals being picked up.

Comment: It's called induction. You have one wire powered up. that creates a fluctuating magnetic field that induces a small amount of current onto a wire right next to it in circuit that is turned off. The voltage might be "up there", but the amount of current will be very low. All transformers work on the principle of induction.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson -- I generally consider E-field (capacitive) coupling to be more significant for phantom voltages than H-field (inductive) coupling...

Comment: This isn’t induction, it’s capacitance. A sufficiently long wire can look like ground to a sensitive device like a digital voltmeter. An old analog meter would show nothing, and a lightbulb wouldn’t light. It’s the same principle used by those neon-lamp voltage detectors: one terminal goes to a (possibly) hot wire, you touch the other terminal, and the neon lamp lights if voltage is present thanks to the capacitance of your body - even though you’re not ground.

Comment: @nobody  I have to respectfully disagree. People  here have had this discussion before and there are certainly disagreements. But I hold that capacitance is the ability to store electricity which is why they are used in electronic devices that have settings that need to be saved during a power outage.   Capacitors have many uses.  One common use is in power supplies that convert AC to DC.  A bridge rectifier with some large capacitors gets you pretty clean DC power.   Once you turn off everything in the affected circuits and get no voltage, that was induction, not capacitance.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson this is most definitely [Capacitive Coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_coupling) and not Induction. Induction requires current flow through through the conductor in order to create a *magnetic* field, and this magnetic field then *induces* current flow in another conductor, which must itself form part of a closed circuit. No current flow -> no magnetic field -> no induction. A transformer is an example of induction in action.

Comment: Capacitive coupling requires an *electric* field coming from a voltage difference between conductors. Simplistically, charge carriers in one conductor attract opposite charge carriers in the other conductor. The AC-coupling between stages of an amplifiers is an example of capacitive coupling.

Comment: Your DVM is just way too sensitive (too high impedance), and it's picking up garbage signals off the airwaves. It might be capacitive coupling from adjacent wires, it might be capacitive coupling from a military ELF antenna or an AM radio station. Who knows, who cares.  It's just a flaw in DVMs.

Comment: So think about something as simple as a door bell transformer. You have no current flow, yet you have voltage on the secondary windings. Induction happens because you have an alternating magnetic field (A/C) that builds a magnetic field, then it collapses 60 times a second (60 hz in the  USA, 50 in Europe), inducting voltage in the secondary windings. It's induction, no two ways about it. Transformers don't store electricity, capacitors do. Think about it. If a lineman came out to do work on the feed to your house, he pulls the fuse off the big transformer on the pole. ...continued below...

Comment: If that big ass transformer acted like a capacitor, he could be dangerously shocked or killed.   You are claiming that just because some wires are running next to each other they can store electricity.  Nonsense, I'm really glad that's not true.

Comment: Soo how can I actually test the wires if I can't trust my DVM?

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson - oh no! you've debunked my bachelors degree in electronics and 25 years of experience!! Or alternatively we could consider the parasitic inter-winding capacitance and core eddy currents in the transformer to explain why we are able to read a voltage on its otherwise-unloaded secondary, and also remember that until we apply some load to the transformer the voltage we read can be substantially higher then the turns ratio would suggest it should be. In fact, transformers *do* store energy because they're *inductors* - they store energy in the magnetic field they create.

Comment: The collapsing magnetic field is the reason for putting snubber circuits or protection diodes across the terminals of anything inductive in a DC(ish) circuit. Capacitors on the other hand store energy in their electric field - and it's a lot easier to maintain the electric field between the 2 'plates' of a capacitor than it is to maintain the magnetic field through the core of an indictor (if you had an indictor with its windings made from a superconductor, then simply shorting the terminals would allow current to continue flowing, and your inductor would store energy indefinitely).

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson It has nothing to do with wires being next to each other - the same thing would happen with a single long unconnected wire. And it only allows a *tiny* amount of electricity to flow (enough for this voltmeter to show a 96V difference when the supply is ~120V). It wouldn’t light a night-light bulb. Capacitance is not on/off as you seem to think.